# Dynamically setVisible ToolBar menu

Tags: android, toolbar

I have 2 EditText and 1 toolbar item which`s invisible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/loginim"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="@string/next"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/back_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Im trying setVisible item menu when EditText fiels are not empty, but app crashing everytime..
My TextWatcher:

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {       }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
    }};
```

Check fields Edit Text:

```
boolean checkFieldsForEmptyValues(){
        String s1 = log.getText().toString();
        String s2 = pass.getText().toString();

        if(!s1.equals("") && !s2.equals("") ){
            MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.loginim);
            View nextItemView = findViewById(nextItem.getItemId());
            nextItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

And method onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);

         log = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_log);
         pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass);

        log.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        pass.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

What's wrong this code??
**UPDATE** LOg:

```
03-09 18:25:01.492    6276-6276/comtime88.vk.myappE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at comtime88.vk.myapp.LoginActivity.checkFieldsForEmptyValues(LoginActivity.java:56)
            at comtime88.vk.myapp.LoginActivity$1.afterTextChanged(LoginActivity.java:37)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
            at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8891)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
            at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:222)
            at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
            at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5385)
            at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5204)
            at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
            at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the error on LogCat?

Comment: What's the line that is crashing?

Comment: Im newbie, so where can I watch line? I dont know :(

Comment: You should be able to look at line 56 of your LoginActivity and see which variable is null. Are you initializing myMenu?

Comment: @mjstam yes, I have `Menu myMenu;` at the start.

Comment: @DenisMolodec Try to put myMenu = menu; in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: @Skizo It doesn`t work anyway, but I found something. If delete this `nextItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` app doesn`t crash..

Answer (score 0):

I guess the line that is crashing is this :

```
MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.loginim);
View nextItemView = findViewById(nextItem.getItemId());
```

I think you should put `myMenu` after `findViewById()` as follows :

```
View nextItemView = myMenu.findViewById(nextItem.getItemId());
```

Let me know if it works, if it doesn't just put the logCat and I'll redo the answer :)

Comment: If  I  put `myMenu` after `findViewById()` it says that `"Cant resolve method findViewById(nextItem.getItemId());"`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
 MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.loginim);
        nextItem.setVisible(true);
```

instead of

```
MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.loginim);
            View nextItemView = findViewById(nextItem.getItemId());
            nextItemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```